# Extension can't access to custom functions in window object

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

When a Chrome extension tries to get custom functions in window object via chrome.executeScript, it gets nothing.

For example:

Tab ID: 150

Tab js:

```
window.customfunc = function(){return 'yeap';}
```

**Extension's background JS:**

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(150, { code: "console.log(window);" })
```

**Manifest.json:**

```
{
   "background": {
      "scripts": [ "background.js" ]
   },
   "content_scripts": [ {
      "exclude_globs": [  ],
      "exclude_matches": [  ],
      "include_globs": [ "*://*/*" ],
      "js": [ "script.js" ],
      "matches": [ "http://*/*" ],
      "run_at": "document_idle"
   } ],
   "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://ssl.google-analytics.com; object-src 'self'",
   "description": "Test",
   "manifest_version": 2,
   "name": "Workspace",
   "permissions": [ "unlimitedStorage", "notifications", "clipboardWrite", "notifications", "clipboardRead", "management", "tabs", "history", "cookies", "idle", "storage", "webRequest", "webRequestBlocking", "contentSettings", "*://*/*" ],
   "version": "1.0"
}
```

**Result:**

In console, the `window` object doesn't show `customfunc`, so we can't use `window.customfunc` with `chrome.executeScript`.

Why does this happen, and how can we fix it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is for security.  Content scripts (which `background.js` is executing) are isolated from the tab's scripts (where `customfunc` is defined).  You also get the added benefit of not having to worry about namespace clashing (which is where things are messing up for you).

One approach would be to create
**myscript.js** which says
`console.log(window)`
and then use a content script (or `chrome.tabs.executeScript`) to write
`<script src='chrome.extension.getURL("myscript.js")'></script>`
to the tab's DOM.  You'll also need to add
`"web_accessible_resources": ["myscript.js"]`
to your manifest.

But with things this complicated, a good question would be why you're needing to access `customfunc`.  (You can also take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/9517879/2336725 for a longer answer.)